# SOAP + PHP | Error: Server was unable to process request. ---> Index was outside the bounds of the array

Tags: php, xml, forms, soap

I'm a PHP beginner and I'm working for the first time with WebServices (SOAP) - integrating a form in a landing page with a customer's CRM. As it is a platform with few customers, I have only one documentation and I am burning my brain with this error, lol.

The data submission process consists of three steps: validation (sending the key and password to generate the token), sending (using the token and sending the form information) and request confirmation (returns the registered lead ID - not required). The validation part has already been done and works, but the sending form is giving the following error:

```
    Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [soap:Server] Server was unable to process request. ---> Index was outside the bounds of the array. in /home2/supera48/guaruja_root/crm4u/apiguaruja.php:58 Stack trace: #0 /home2/supera48/guaruja_root/crm4u/apiguaruja.php(58): SoapClient->__soapCall('PutLead', Array, Array) #1 {main} thrown in /home2/supera48/guaruja_root/crm4u/apiguaruja.php on line 58
```

After generating the token, I must send the form data in the following format:

```
        <soapenv:Header/>
        <soapenv:Body>
            <tem:PutLead>
                <tem:pessoa>
                    <tem:Nome>LEAD'S NAME</tem:Nome>
                    <tem:Email>LEAD@EMAIL.COM</tem:Email>
                    <tem:Telefone>999999999</tem:Telefone>
                    <tem:Observacoes>DETAILS</tem:Observacoes>
                </tem:pessoa>
                <tem:Key>TOKEN GENERATED IN VALIDATION</tem:Key>
            </tem:PutLead>
        </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

If the submission is confirmed, it returns an ID to me - like this:

```
        <soap:Body>
            <PutLeadResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
                <PutLeadResult>ID DO LEAD</PutLeadResult>
            </PutLeadResponse>
        </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>
```

I take and attach here the code of the submission form and the script I'm running:

FORM:

```
    <form id="formulario" action="api.php" method="post">
    <div width="100%">
        <input type="text" id="nome" name="nome" class="campos" placeholder="Seu nome" required>
    </div>
    <div width="100%">
        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="campos" placeholder="Seu e-mail" required>
    <div width="100%">
        <input type="tel" id="telefone" name="telefone" class="campos" placeholder="Seu celular" required>
    </div>    
    <div width="100%" class="motivo">
        <select id ="observacoes" name="observacoes">
        <option value="Selecionar">----- Com o que podemos te ajudar?</option>
        <option value="Concurso e vestibular">Concurso e vestibular</option>
        <option value="Inteligência">Inteligência</option>
        <option value="Memória">Memória</option>
        <option value="Profissional">Profissional</option>
        <option value="Alzheimer">Alzheimer</option>
        <option value="Ansiedade">Ansiedade</option>
        <option value="Atenção">Atenção</option>
        <option value="Estresse">Estresse</option>
        <option value="Estudo">Estudo</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div width="100%" align="center">
        <button id="enviar" name="enviar" type="submit" class="btn-enviar">Enviar</button>
    </div>
    </form>
```

API.PHP

```
    <?php

    $nome = $_POST['nome'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $telefone = $_POST['telefone'];
    $observacoes = $_POST['observacoes'];


    $client = new SoapClient('http://crm4u.azurewebsites.net/WS_Integracao.asmx?WSDL');

    $function = 'GetToken';

    $arguments= array('GetToken' => array(
                                            'ApiKey'   => XXXXXXX
                                          )
                     );

    $options = array('location' => 'http://crm4u.azurewebsites.net/WS_Integracao.asmx');

    $result = $client->__soapCall($function, $arguments, $options);

    $json = $result->GetTokenResult;
    $item = json_decode($json, true);

    print_r($item);

    $apikey = 'XXXXXXX';

    $apipassword = 'YYYYYYYY';

    $combinacao = $apikey."|".$apipassword."|".$item;

    $combinacaomd5 = md5($combinacao);

    $tokenfinal = $combinacaomd5."|".$apikey;

    print_r($tokenfinal);

    $argumentsPost = array('PutLead' => array(
                                'Pessoa'   => array(
                                        'Nome'   => $nome,
                                        'Email'   => $email,
                                        'Telefone'   => $telefone,
                                        'Observacoes'   => $observacoes
                                ),
                                'Key' => array(
                                    'ApiKey'   => $tokenfinal
                                  )
                                )
                            );

    $optionsPost = array('location' => 'http://crm4u.azurewebsites.net/WS_Integracao.asmx');

    $functionPost = 'PutLead';

    $resultPost = $client->__soapCall($functionPost, $argumentsPost, $optionsPost);

    ?>
```

The error, according to the script, is on the penultimate line (58). I don't know what I can do differently, or I'm doing incorrectly, but I suspect it may be related to the fact that "Person" is inside "PutLead". Despite this, I already tested $functionPost by calling 'Person', but the error persisted.

Does anyone have any idea how I can solve this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no *lol* because the service works as designed. Let us find out, why your soap client throws this error.

First have a look at the definitions in the wsdl. For the `PutLead` method the parameter is defined as follows.

```
<s:element name="PutLead">
    <s:complexType>
        <s:sequence>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="pessoa" type="tns:Lead"/>
            <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Key" type="s:string"/>
        </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
</s:element>
```

To execute the `PutLead` webservice method correctly, there is a complex type `PutLead` defined, that has to elements `pessoa` and `Key`. The element `pessoa` is defined as tns:Lead type. The `Key` element is a simple string. A complex type definition can be seen as an php data value object. a simple object, that holds data. So let us define a php object for the `PutLead` complex type.

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);
namespace Application\Model;

class PutLead
{
    protected ?Lead $pessoa;
    protected ?string $Key;

    public function getPessoa(): ?Lead
    {
        return $this->pessoa;
    }

    public function setPessoa(Lead $pessoa): self
    {
        $this->pessoa = $pessoa;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getKey(): ?string
    {
        return $this->Key();
    }

    public function setKey(string $key): self
    {
        $this->Key = $key;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

This php value object recognizes all the definitions from the wsdl complex type definition `PutLead`. The two properties can exactly occur zero or one time. The `Key` property is a string type and the `pessoa` property can be a Lead object.

What says the wsdl about the `tns:Lead` definition?

```
<s:complexType name="Lead">
    <s:sequence>
        <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Id" type="s:int"/>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Nome" type="s:string"/>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Email" type="s:string"/>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Telefone" type="s:string"/>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Observacoes" type="s:string"/>
        <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="Campanha" type="s:string"/>
        <s:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="Unidade_Id" type="s:int"/>
    </s:sequence>
</s:complexType>
```

Here we can see, why your client is throwing a soap fault with the message `object has no 'Id' property`. The `pessoa` complex type must contain an `Id` property and an `Unidade_Id` property. Both were not defined and so the webservice throws an error.

The php value object must look like this:

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);
namespace Application\Model;

class Lead
{
    protected int $Id;
    protected ?string $Nome;
    protected ?string $Email;
    protected ?string $Telefone;
    protected ?string $Observacoes;
    protected ?string $Campanha;
    protected int $Unidade_Id;

    public function getId(): int
    {
        return $this->Id;
    }

    public function setId(int $id): self
    {
        $this->Id = $id;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getNome(): ?string
    {
        return $this->Nome;
    }

    public function setNome(string $nome): self
    {
        $this->Nome = $nome;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getEmail(): ?string
    {
        return $this->Email;
    }

    public function setEmail(string $email): self
    {
        $this->Email = $email;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getTelefone(): ?string
    {
        return $this->Telefone;
    }

    public function setTelefone(string $telefone): self
    {
        $this->Telefone = $telefone;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getObservacoes(): ?string
    {
        return $this->Observacoes;
    }

    public function setObservacoes(string $observacoes): self
    {
        $this->Observacoes = $observacoes;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getCampanha(): ?string
    {
        return $this->Campanha;
    }

    public function setCampanha(string $campanha): self
    {
        $this->Campanha = $campanha;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getUnidadeId(): int
    {
        return $this->Unidade_Id;
    }

    public function setUnidadeId(int $unidadeId): self
    {
        $this->Unidade_Id = $unidadeId;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

The above shown php value object reflects exactly the `tns:Lead` complex type definition. With the two defined php value objects you can execute the `PutLead` request.

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);
namespace Application;

use Application\Model\Lead;
use Application\Model\PutLead;
use SoapClient;
use SoapFault;

try {
    $wsdl = 'http://crm4u.azurewebsites.net/WS_Integracao.asmx?WSDL';
    $options = [
        'exceptions' => true,
        'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1,
        'trace' = true,
    ];

    $client = new SoapClient($wsdl, $options);

    // request for a valid key
    $key = ...;

    // the following variables $id, $nome, $email, $telefone, $observacoes
    // $campanha and $unidadeId must be declared before the following init
    $pessoa = (new Lead())
        ->setId($id)
        ->setNome($nome)
        ->setEmail($email)
        ->setTelefone($telefone)
        ->setObservacoes($observacoes)
        ->setCampanha($campanha)
        ->setUnidadeId($unidadeId)

    $putLead = (new PutLead())
        ->setPessoa($pessoa)
        ->setKey($key);

    $result = $client->PutLead($putLead);
} catch (SoapFault $fault) {
    var_dump($fault);
}
```

As you can see the `SoapClient` class is initialized with the wsdl address and some options, that force the soap client to throw exceptions as `SoapFault` instances. Furthermore you can trace the request and response with `SoapClient::__getLastRequest()` and `SoapClient::__getLastResponse()`. If the client was initialized without throwing an error, you can use these methods to have a look at the last sent request and the last received response, if any was received. This can be very helpful when debugging the whole process.

Comment: Marcel, many thanks for the complete answer!
I was left with just one question: how will we not define the lead ID (it will be generated when the form is sent, and will return as success), how do I proceed when sending it? In your comments on the code, you are asked to define the $Id string.
Thanks again!

Comment: Since the `Id` and `Unidade_Id` are defined as required in the complex type `Lead` in the wsdl you have to send both in the `PutLead` request. Have a look at the `minoccurs` parameter. As long as these two poperties are defined as `minoccurs="1"` you have to send them.  If you don 't want to send the `Id` or `Unidade_Id` properties, you have to change the wsdl. If you 're not the webservice provider, you have to talk to the webservice provider if it is possible to send a `PutLead` request without `Id` and `Unidade_Id` properties.

Comment: You can try to download the wsdl content and store it in s local copy. Change the `minoccurs` parameter for `Id` and `Unidade_Id` to 0 and initialize the soap client with your local wsdl file. But I guess, that the provider validates the incoming data and throws an exception in any way.

Comment: Marcel, thanks again!
I'm not the WebService provider - I'll need to talk with them.
I try to run the script like you said, and the follow error appeared:
```Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?', expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST) in /home2/supera48/guaruja_root/crm4u/apiguaruja.php on line 47```

Comment: Line 47:
```protected ?Lead $pessoa;```

Comment: This error message could be because of a PHP version lower than 7.4. Just leave out the type hints and change it to `protected $propertyName;`. PHP versions lower than 7.4 don 't support type hints for object properties.

Comment: So ```protected ?Lead $pessoa;``` will be ```protected $propertyLead;```?
Thanks again!

Comment: No ... the class members must reflect the names of the elements in the complex types. Therefore you have to write it like `protected $pessoa;`. Just don 't mention the type hints `?Lead`.

Answer (score 0):

I notice that "Pessoa" on WDSL was lowercase, and I changed it on my code. Now I got this:

```
<?php

    $nome = $_POST['nome'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $telefone = $_POST['telefone'];
    $observacoes = $_POST['observacoes'];


    $client = new SoapClient('http://crm4u.azurewebsites.net/WS_Integracao.asmx?WSDL');

    $function = 'GetToken';

    $arguments= array('GetToken' => array(
                                            'ApiKey'   => XXXXXXX
                                          )
                     );

    $options = array('location' => 'http://crm4u.azurewebsites.net/WS_Integracao.asmx');

    $result = $client->__soapCall($function, $arguments, $options);

    $json = $result->GetTokenResult;
    $item = json_decode($json, true);

    print_r($item);

    $apikey = 'XXXXXXX';

    $apipassword = 'YYYYYYYY';

    $combinacao = $apikey."|".$apipassword."|".$item;

    $combinacaomd5 = md5($combinacao);

    $tokenfinal = $combinacaomd5."|".$apikey;

    print_r($tokenfinal);

    $argumentsPost = array('PutLead' => array(
                                'pessoa'   => array(
                                        'Nome'   => $nome,
                                        'Email'   => $email,
                                        'Telefone'   => $telefone,
                                        'Observacoes'   => $observacoes
                                ),
                                'Key' => array(
                                    'ApiKey'   => $tokenfinal
                                  )
                                )
                            );

    $optionsPost = array('location' => 'http://crm4u.azurewebsites.net/WS_Integracao.asmx');

    $functionPost = 'PutLead';

    $resultPost = $client->__soapCall($functionPost, $argumentsPost, $optionsPost);

    ?>
```

Now the error changed, lol:
`Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'Id' property in /home2/supera48/guaruja_root/crm4u/apiguaruja.php:56 Stack trace: #0 /home2/supera48/guaruja_root/crm4u/apiguaruja.php(56): SoapClient->__soapCall('PutLead', Array, Array) #1 {main} thrown in /home2/supera48/guaruja_root/crm4u/apiguaruja.php on line 56`

Does anyone have a guess?

Thanks!