# Server was unable to process request. ---> Index was out of range

Tags: php, api

I'm getting this error:
*Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [soap:Server] Server was unable to process request. ---> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index in /var/www/index.php:30 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/index.php(30): SoapClient->__call() #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/index.php on line 30*

My php-code is:

```
<?php

    ini_set('error_log', '/var/www/php.log');

    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

    include("include/connection.php");

    $client = new SoapClient("https:// (LINK TO API) /ExternalApiWebService.asmx?wsdl", array('trace' => 1));

    // **--** Login - START **--**
    $LoginResult = $client->Login(
        array("userName" => "USERNAME", "password" => "PASSWORD"
        )
    );

    print "<pre>";
    print_r ($LoginResult);
    print "</pre>";

    $SessionId = $LoginResult->LoginResult;
    // **--** Login - END **--**

    // **--** GetTriplogUnitPositions - START **--**
    $GetTriplogUnitPositionsResult = $client->GetTriplogUnitPositions(
        array("sessionId" => "".$SessionId.""
        )
    );

    print "<pre>";
    print_r ($GetTriplogUnitPositionsResult);
    print "</pre>";
    // **--** GetTriplogUnitPositions - END **--**

?>
```

Can anyone help me or give me a hint of whats wrong?

Comment: Debugging SOAP is why many of us that lived through avoid it like the plague. I don’t see anything obvious in your code, I think you might have to inspect the WSDL. there’s a great post on how to do it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61560593/231316

Comment: Thanks for your answer... My code "suddenly" works again. The API owners say they were nothing wrong with the API, but I do not know if I should believe them :)
But it works now and I'm happy